# (concurrently not found) trying to deploy a PERN app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, deployment

I'm having trouble deploying an app to heroku. I'm fairly new to whole deployment aspect of web development so I may be doing this wrong, but I have an issue where concurrently is not found with the `heroku logs --tail` command.

```
2022-04-20T18:47:38.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-04-20T18:47:40.486475+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-04-20T18:47:41.658492+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-04-20T18:47:41.658506+00:00 app[web.1]: > walk-the-cat@1.0.0 start
2022-04-20T18:47:41.658507+00:00 app[web.1]: > concurrently "nodemon server.js" "cd ./client && npm 
start"
2022-04-20T18:47:41.658507+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-04-20T18:47:41.677532+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: concurrently: not found
2022-04-20T18:47:41.839383+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2022-04-20T18:47:42.018496+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-04-20T18:47:42.036732+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-04-20T18:47:47.044533+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-04-20T18:47:48.418408+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-04-20T18:47:48.418419+00:00 app[web.1]: > walk-the-cat@1.0.0 start
2022-04-20T18:47:48.418419+00:00 app[web.1]: > concurrently "nodemon server.js" "cd ./client && npm 
start"
```

I have concurrently under devDependencies and I understand that Heroku prunes out devDependent packages.

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server.js",
    "start": "concurrently \"nodemon server.js\" \"cd ./client && npm start\"",
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/walk-the-cat/walk-the-cat.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/walk-the-cat/walk-the-cat/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/walk-the-cat/walk-the-cat#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^4.19.5",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "pg": "^8.7.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^7.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

I tried going around the pruning process with `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION = false`, but still same error.
Is there anyway I can deploy with concurrently? Or is the way I'm trying just completely wrong and not good practice? I've been searching and I've seen others who deployed server and client separately for one Heroku App? But I'm not sure if I should start running down that rabbit hole.
I also saw something about dealing with Procfiles, so I might start looking into that as well.

Comment: You can't bind two things to one port anyway. Why not build the react app and get express to serve it? And why use nodemon in prod?

Comment: What do you mean by two things to one port? I though since nodemon kept the server running through any changes it would be a good idea to keep in production, I guess not. Any doc or reference for having express serve the react app? Sorry for the dummy questions, I started diving into programming a couple months ago

Comment: One port for the backend, one for the frontend dev server. What changes are going to be made _on Heroku_? When you update the source code, you deploy a new instance. Here's one I set up earlier: https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit

Answer (score 0):

The `concurrently` package doesn't work with heroku, instead you need to tell Heroku what to do specifically. Also, you shouldn't be running `nodemon` in an Heroku application, there is no need for it.

Heroku needs exact instructions in it's `postbuild` script, I don't know your folder structure, but according to your `start` script I've written the following example:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node server.js",
  "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build && ../ && npm install"
},
```

This should get you started, but in this case I am telling Heroku to go into the `client` folder and install npm packages then run build which builds the react application in prod. Then go back into where we started (which I believe in your case is the server.js root) and install those packages. Now Heroku knows how to run your app.